# Gnome Terminal not showing up in unity, Why?

Tags: unity, command-line, workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, how do I see the applications open on different workspaces.

The issue that I am having is that I have opened 3 instances gnome-terminal and have minimized them; the unity launcher isn't showing any of the terminal application I guess they might be on another workspace.

---

To my surprise, i am noticing that the terminal are not showing up on unity launcher. This is bugging me.

Any logs that I could paste here, that would help in tshooting.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. The terminal did not show up in the Laucher or when using Alt+Tab. This was after migrating my Ubuntu 12.04 installation to a new laptop.

Solution: Uninstall gnome-terminal using Ubuntu software center and re-install it right afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

On your launcher, on the left side of the screen, at the bottom should be this button:

[image]

Whenever you click it, it should sprawl out all of your workspaces, and you can see what windows are open.

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open up all of your workspaces as well.

Answer (score 2):

If they are in a different workspace, hold Super/Windows button and S . This will show you all thw workspaces. Click on whichever workspace you would like to view.

Answer (score 2):

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Key</kbd> to quickly switch workspaces in the direction of the arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/149442/why-do-some-programs-not-remain-on-the-dashboard. I don't believe this is to do with workspaces - I see programs appearing in the launcher whatever workspace they are in and never see terminal at all. Also I cannot switch to terminal with alt+tab - this means that if another window is in front of terminal then the only way to get back is to move the other window. Minimising a terminal rendered it completely inaccessible. From the system monitor I was able to confirm that terminal was still running and kill it, but not switch back to it. (Then I clicked the system monitor's title bar and the click went straight through to the program behind it - but that's a separate issue.) This appears to be a bug in Unity (and possibly also gnome-terminal). The most obvious solution for me is to switch back to gnome classic.

Comment: yes exactly i was having the same issue, but after restarting the issue faded away. Most probably this would be a bug in unity.